# Should I use AJAX?

Tags: ajax, visualization

I am trying to develop a web based document browsing system, that could look possibly something like : http://www.cell.com/trends/biochemical-sciences (then click on "Protein kinases: evolution of dynamic regulatory proteins").

What web technologies should I look at using? AJAX?

Thanks in advance.

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX could do the trick, but you'll need more than that.

Getting document sections and pictures with AJAX is half (maybe less than half) the job, as you'll need all the backend code to upload documents, maybe extract document sections from PDF, store documents hierarchically, retrieve the document hierarchy and pictures, and so on.

Moreover, you don't even told us what server-side technology you are going to use... Java, PHP, DotNet... and the database... PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, end the list goes on.

About the AJAX side and web UI, I suggest you take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have most of the backend stuff done - have collections of documents, extracted all that I need from PDF/DOC etc. I am using MySQL to store all the text information. Pictures are sitting on my hard disk. What else did you want to know? I do know very little web programming (a bit of HTML) so I apologize if I am not giving any information.

Comment: @Andy If you already successfully coded all of that you probably have most of the needed knowledge on the how-to, just missing the practical HTML/JS usage. I suggest you dive a bit recklessly into it, as you won't perfect your code before you realize something is being done the hard way or it simply suck. Check the w3school tutorials on HTML and JS just to know how far they can go, then move to jQuery.